# Default Dict append Attribute Error 'float' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list, append, attributeerror, defaultdict

I have read all the script from default dict and all the posts on here. I believe my syntax is correct.

```
influenceDict = defaultdict(list)
```

to fill with all tags from all tweets

Later, I am appending ALOT of float values, 1000+ list entries for a majority of dictionary keys. I get my error on line 47, specified below.

```
def addInfluenceScores(hashtagArr,numFollowers,numRetweets, influenceDict):

    influenceScore = float(0)

    if numFollowers == 0 and numRetweets != 0:

        influenceScore = numRetweets + 1

    elif numFollowers == 0 and numRetweets == 0:
        influenceScore = 0

    else:

        influenceScore = numRetweets / numFollowers

    print "Adding influence score %f to individual hashtags" % (influenceScore)

    for tag in hashtagArr:

        tID = tag2id_map[tag]

        print "Appending ",tID,tag

        # if not influenceDict.has_key(tID):

        #   influenceDict[tID] = list()

        #   influenceDict[tID].append(influenceScore)

        # else:

        #   influenceDict[tID].append(influenceScore)

        influenceDict[tID].append(influenceScore) **#LINE 47 I GET THE ERROR HERE**

    for i in range(len(hashtagArr)):

        for j in range(i+1, len(hashtagArr)):

            tID1 = tag2id_map[hashtagArr[i]]

            tID2 = tag2id_map[hashtagArr[j]]

            if(tID2 < tID1): #ensure alpha order to avoid duplicating (a,b) and (b,a)

                temp = tID1

                tID1 = tID2

                tID2 = temp

                print "Appending ",tID1, hashtagArr[j],tID2,hashtagArr[i]

            # if not influenceDict.has_key((tID1, tID2)):

            #   influenceDict[(tID1, tID2)] = list()

            #   influenceDict[(tID1, tID2)].append(influenceScore)
            # else:

            #   influenceDict[(tID1, tID2)].append(influenceScore)

                influenceDict[(tID1, tID2)].append(influenceScore)


The program runs for a while, and it actually does append values (or so I think) and then I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./scripts/make_id2_influencescore_maps.py", line 158, in <module

    processTweets(tweets, influenceDict)

  File "./scripts/make_id2_influencescore_maps.py", line 127, in processTweets

    addInfluenceScores(hashtags, numFollowers,numRetweets, influenceDict)

  File "./scripts/make_id2_influencescore_maps.py", line 47, in addInfluenceScores

   influenceDict[tID].append(influenceScore)

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I am thinking that the list is just maxed out in memory. Maybe you guys can see something I don't. I am trying to loop through a file of tweets and for everytime I see the hashtag I want to append a score to the list associated with it. That way I can just take the average of all the scores in the list when I am completely done reading the file. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking that the list is just maxed out in memory.

I can assure you thats not the case if your error is

```
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'append'
```

The problem is not in the code you have shown here, as `influenceDict` is a parameter you have obviously set one of the keys to point to a `float` value elsewhere in your code. Just because it is a `defaultdict(list)` that doesn't prevent this from occurring.